# Does Ubuntu with Linux 3.5 having TX RX ring buffers or BQL

Tags: linux, networking, nic, udp, multicast

My linux uname -a command outputs:

```
Linux Davinci001 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So, does NICs with this Ubuntu machine is working with BQL (Byte Queue Limit) algorithms or TX and RX ring buffers?

ethtool command displays this:

Ring parameters for eth1:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             2040
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       8160
TX:             255
Current hardware settings:
RX:             255
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             255

How can I know if BQL is currently running or old TX RX ring buffer mechanisms running in NIC driver.

I need this information to resolve problem: I have UDP packet losses in particular multicasts where bitrate high and bursty.

If BQL is running, then how can I turn it off and start old TX and RX ring buffer mechanisms.

Comment: Do you have to use an old and unsupported kernel? Or, for that matter, Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your meaning. Can you please explain me?